# I dont get a result in the console [c++]

Tags: c++, arrays

I've created a 2D array with length and width.

My minGW compiler says nothing to build.
Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int rows = 5;
const int coloms = 5;
int Matrix[rows][coloms];

void ClearMatrix()
{
    for(int i=0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j < coloms; j++)
        {
            Matrix[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

void ShowMatrix()
{
    for(int i; i < rows; i++)
    {
         for(int j; j < coloms; j++)
         {
            cout<< Matrix[i][j];
         }
    }
}

int main()
{
    ClearMatrix();
    ShowMatrix();
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What command are you using to compile this?

Comment: But when i add a line of code cout<<"text"; to the int main() {} 
it only prints text

Comment: The problem is not in the code, but in the command you're trying to use to build the executable. How are you trying to compile? Please post whatever commands you are using.

Comment: @automaton No, that has nothing to do with it. As mentioned in the answer there are uninitalized variables used in the loop.

Comment: I am using eclipse neon with minGW compiler...i dont see any code on the eclipse command line

Comment: @Anonymous It works fine is you fix the uninitialized variables: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/127964fb8ebc1a95

Comment: @Anonymous Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  for(int i; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for(int j; j < coloms; j++)
     {
            cout<< Matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
```

You are accessing `i` and `j` which are uninitialized local variables. So, it's an undefined behavior.

Comment: Im sorry but didnt under stand please elaborate

Comment: OP says "but my minGW compiler says nothing to build." Does not sound like he's even reaching the point where this would matter.

Comment: @Anonymous If you don't understand what that means, please search this site and elsewhere for that information.

Comment: You can google what is Undefined behavior. In case of UB, any thing can happen. The behavior can't be predicted.

Comment: @SauravSahu I didn't understand

Comment: @Anonymous What don't you understand? You did that correct in the 1st function and missed it in the 2nd.

Comment: @SauravSahu Ohhhh k i get it tysm :)

Comment: I have used Matrix[i][j] in both 1st and 2nd function.... [im sorr
y if that sounded stupid, im new to c++]

Comment: @Anonymous _"But i dont get that error in eclipse..."_ Well, undefined behavior is eeerm undefined.

Comment: What did you exactly change? I am sorry I am very new to c++ (5 hours new please have mercy)

Comment: Solution : Just set `i` and `j` to `0`, before firing up the `for` loops

Comment: It worked but i do not know what changed in the [correctCode](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/127964fb8ebc1a95)

Comment: You need to learn the programming language step by step, else everything would appear to you like a magic. ATB

Comment: Pffffff my 12 year old brain [im 16] I got it thanks to every one im just horrible, it defines my computer grades very well [ i got a c]